# The INSERT Satatement Confliceted with the FOREIGN KEY Contraint

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am creating a project on courier service. I got this error when I tried to enter values at run time. I have 2 insert statements, one for the sender and the other for Receiver. But the problem exists in insert statement for Sender and in LoginID. Actually, I want to add the logged user in "Sender" Table, so that I can see, how much entries, the logged user did. First, I am getting LoginID from the "Login" table using this statement

```
log_id = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][0]);
```

Where log_id is an integer variable. And dt is a data table name

It works perfectly. I have seen it by using messagebox.

And then I created a Public Variable to use it on other forms.

```
public int logId
{
    get { return log_id; }
}
```

Then I called this variable on my data entry form like this.

```
public StdExpIntl(int logId)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    logID = logId;
}
```

And this is my Insert Statement

```
Insert into Sender(CourierNo,LoginID,SenderName) values ('" + cNo.Text + "','"+logID+"', '" + Name1.Text + "')", con);
```

This is not the full statement, but I guess it is ok for now.

Login table

```
LoginID numeric(18, 0)  NOT NULL
StaffID varchar(15) NOT NULL
username    varchar(10) NOT NULL
password    varchar(10) NOT NULL
```

Sender Table

```
CourierNo   varchar(15) NOT NULL
LoginID numeric(18, 0)  NOT NULL
SenderName  text    NOT NULL
SenderNIC   numeric(18, 0)  NOT NULL
SenderCountry   text    NOT NULL
SenderState text    NOT NULL
```

The error is in LoginID, please someone help me.

Comment: Use parameters, that's your bigger problem.

Comment: Can you please explain

Comment: Also i dont see a reason why you would insert a primary key cant you have it autoincremented or generated

Comment: No, It is not auto generated, it just gives me the logged user's Login ID so that I can see how much entries the logged user has done.

Comment: The code you posted won't even compile. Show us your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

I see the following: 
the insert statement uses *single quotation* around each parameter to insert, including **LogID**. Since LogID is numeric, it would not need this, so your insert statement should look like this:

```
Insert into Sender(CourierNo,LoginID,SenderName) values ('" + cNo.Text + "',"+logID+", '" + Name1.Text + "');
```

to prevent micro-managing your queries in such a way, you can make use of parameterizing your queries.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Insert into Sender(CourierNo,LoginID,SenderName) values (@courierNo, @loginId, @senderName)",connection))
    {

        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("courierNo", cNo.Text));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("loginId", logID));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("senderName", Name1.Text));
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to include `@` in the `new SqlParameter` names, and probably want to add `.Value = something` to your `Parameters.Add()`s.

Comment: @Dour High Arch: Is what you say a more generic implementation? As it stand it should work for sql server, save that i forgot to add the connection object in the sqlcommand construction, which i now added.

Comment: I meant use the `SqlParameter` with [data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like `command.Parameters.Add(
    "@courierNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cNo.Text`.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting a variable to itself.

```
public StdExpIntl(int logId)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        logID = logId;
    }
```

You want...

```
public StdExpIntl(int logId)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        log_id = logId;
    }
```

Comment: Also, logID is StdExpIntl's local variable and logId is the imported variable, there is a difference.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
Insert into Sender(CourierNo,LoginID,SenderName) values 
('" + cNo.Text + "'," + logID + ", '" + Name1.Text + "')", con);
```

I have removed single quote around logID